# SSAS tabular - Grant deploy permission without giving the admin role

Tags: security, permissions, roles, ssas-tabular

Is there a way to give to someone the deployment rights of a cube ssas without giving it the admin role?
For example, i want to give the possibility to an intern to deploy his own cube but without the possibility to do anything to others cubes.